# General question about limits

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

Assume we have functions $f, g, h$. We know that $g$ grows exponentially faster than $h$. Can we now conclude that

$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac {f(x)}{g(x)-h(x)}=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac {f(x)}{g(x)}$ ?

If not, what would be sufficient conditions for this?

Comment: Provided that the limit on the right-hand side exists and $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{h(x)}{g(x)}=0$, yes.

Comment: @egreg Yes, the limit does exist. Thank you very much!

Comment: @egreg as the question propably isn't of public interest, should I delete it now?

Comment: @PeterGarder Never delete a question unless it has some serious problem(s).

Comment: What does exponentially faster mean exactly ?

Comment: Just use the algebra of limit rather than craft such rules for specific situations. Note that $$\frac{f(x)} {g(x) - h(x)} =\frac{f(x)} {g(x)} \cdot\frac{1}{1-(h(x)/g(x) )}$$ and since $h/g\to 0$ the desired equality holds without any further constraints. But isn't it better to write the above equation during your limit evaluation (which just adds one extra step) instead of trying to frame new rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exists (finite or infinite) and that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{h(x)}{g(x)}=0$. Then
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=
1\cdot\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{1-\frac{h(x)}{g(x)}}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{1-\frac{h(x)}{g(x)}}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)-h(x)}
$$
Note that there's no need for “faster exponential growth”, just that the limit of $h(x)/g(x)$ is $0$.

Be careful when you make up “new rules”: it's quite easy to forget some of the required hypotheses.

Answer (score 1):

With $u(x)=f(x)/(g(x)-h(x))$ and $v(x)=f(x)/g(x),$ if $f(x)\ne 0$ we have $v(x)/u(x)=1-h(x)/g(x).$